# Multi scale CNN Network Python

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, keras, convolutional-neural-network

I created a multi-scale CNN in python keras. The network architecture is similar to the diagram. Here, same image is fed to 3 CNN's with different architectures. The weights are NOT shared.

[image]

I coded the following multiscale CNN in keras which loosely resembles the architecture in the diagram. But I keep getting **"Out of memory ERROR"** even when the train_dir has 2 images. Would appreciate help...

```
#main CNN model - CNN1
main_model = Sequential()
main_model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape=(3, 224, 224)))
main_model.add(Activation('relu'))
main_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

main_model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3))
main_model.add(Activation('relu'))
main_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

main_model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3))
main_model.add(Activation('relu'))
main_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))) # the main_model so far outputs 3D feature maps (height, width, features)

main_model.add(Flatten())

#lower features model - CNN2
lower_model1 = Sequential()
lower_model1.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape=(3, 224, 224)))
lower_model1.add(Activation('relu'))
lower_model1.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
lower_model1.add(Flatten())

#lower features model - CNN3
lower_model2 = Sequential()
lower_model2.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, input_shape=(3, 224, 224)))
lower_model2.add(Activation('relu'))
lower_model2.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
lower_model2.add(Flatten())

#merged model
merged_model = Merge([main_model, lower_model1, lower_model2], mode='concat')

final_model = Sequential()                     
final_model.add(merged_model)                  
final_model.add(Dense(64))
final_model.add(Activation('relu'))
final_model.add(Dropout(0.5))      
final_model.add(Dense(1))
final_model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
final_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

print 'About to start training merged CNN'
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2, horizontal_flip=True)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_data_dir, target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=32, class_mode='binary')

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(args.test_images, target_size=(224, 224), batch_size=32, class_mode='binary')

final_train_generator = zip(train_generator, train_generator, train_generator)
final_test_generator  = zip(test_generator, test_generator, test_generator)
final_model.fit_generator(final_train_generator, samples_per_epoch=nb_train_samples, nb_epoch=nb_epoch, validation_data=final_test_generator, nb_val_samples=nb_validation_samples)
```

**UPDATE 1:** Providing more system info

I am using Theano-0.9.0.dev5 | Keras-1.2.1 | Python 2.7.12 | OSX Sierra 10.12.3 (16D32) | Macbook Pro 16GB RAM | CPU mode

`~/.keras/keras.json` contents

```
{
    "image_dim_ordering": "th",
    "epsilon": 1e-07,
    "floatx": "float64",
    "backend": "theano"
}
```

Dont have `.theanorc` file

Please note individual CNN models are training fine. Only the merged code above causes issues.

**UPDATE 2:** on 27th January, 2017. Tried the following -

1. Reduced the no. of parameters of the CNN from 53 million to 100K. But still no use. The network eventually fails to train due to memory issues.
2. Reduced the batch size of images training to 8. The network training fails with the same reason.

No working solution at the time of writing this update...

Comment: Some extra information would be useful for diagnosing the problem: version of keras, theano/tensorflow, cudnn and CUDA. Operating system. Configuration of keras (.keras/keras.conf) telling whether you are using GPU or CPU, etc. Configuration of theano/tensorflow; e.g. in .theanorc you can specify the memory management thresholds. Model of your GPU and its amount of RAM (if you are using a GPU).

Comment: @ncasas please find the update to the question with the data you requested. I also tried the same code in AWS GPU instances which resulted in the same issue https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01M0AXXQB

Comment: Have you tried with `float32` instead of `float64` in the keras configuration?

Comment: @ncasas yes just now changed to float32. Still same issue. code runs for 10minutes hogging RAM till it reaches around 40GB and is killed...

Comment: @ncasas I just tried final_model.summary() to see how many parameters used in the model. It shows 53 million parameters :o How is that possible? is my code wrong? The CNN's I defined are fairly simple...

Comment: Have you been able to fix this? Have you tried to comment your code line-by-line to see how that affects the number of parameters?

Comment: @RicardoCruz please read update2 above... No working solution found yet..

Comment: Did you try to run this on a Amazon AWS p2x large instance? At spot price they go for about $0.40 per hour. I was running into problems on CPU and AWS instance with K50 that did not happen on p2x large. Maybe worth a try?

Comment: @Stereo Can you update your new architecture keras code after you reduce numbers of parameters?

Comment: @SrikarAppalaraju, could you try placing a Dense(4096), Desne(4x4x96) and Dense(4x4x96) layers after Flattening them and then merging?

Comment: It is certainly possible to run a network of this size on CPU. Your RAM matters less than the amount of HD available for virtual memory. How much free space is on your machine?

I second the recommendation of others that you try this on an EC2 instance. p2x large should be enough.

Also, Keras tends to keep tons of memory allocated when you have multiple compiled models going. Are you using jupyter notebooks? Try making sure you only have one running at a time.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following function to determine how much memory your model requires:

```
def get_model_memory_usage(batch_size, model):
    import numpy as np
    from keras import backend as K

    shapes_mem_count = 0
    for l in model.layers:
        single_layer_mem = 1
        for s in l.output_shape:
            if s is None:
                continue
            single_layer_mem *= s
        shapes_mem_count += single_layer_mem

    trainable_count = np.sum([K.count_params(p) for p in set(model.trainable_weights)])
    non_trainable_count = np.sum([K.count_params(p) for p in set(model.non_trainable_weights)])

    total_memory = 4.0*batch_size*(shapes_mem_count + trainable_count + non_trainable_count)
    gbytes = np.round(total_memory / (1024.0 ** 3), 3)
    return gbytes
```

I copied this from ZFTurbo's answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43137288/how-to-determine-needed-memory-of-keras-model) post.